# I get this error: ConnectionBad: connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rubygems

I am trying to connect a rails app to Postgresql db locally and I get that message when I run db:create.
here is my database.yml file:

```yaml
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  username: postgres
  password: alex70gou
  host: localhost

  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: artur_development
```

I have tried `ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD 'alex70gou';` and get the same result, and other things including uninstalling and reinstalling postgresql.

Comment: What error message is in the postgresql server log file?  It should match the client message, but also have additional DETAIL entries.

Answer (score 0):

sudo -u postgres psql

create user deployer with password 'deployer';
alter user deployer superuser;

username: deployer
password: deployer

Don't use system user for app connections

Answer (score 0):

Try `psql -U postgres`

`postgres=#\password`

You’ll be prompted to enter a new password.